# 3D graphics are not rendering properly

Tags: graphics3d, linux, rendering

I have noticed that on my installation of Mathematica 12.1 on Fedora 31 3D graphics do not render properly. Whenever opacity is specified for an object it disappears altogether (it is a rendering issue, there are no problems with exported figures). I have tried changing the "3DRenderingEngine" from "Automatic" to "Mesa" and that fixes the problem, however animations become extremely slow. If I set it to "OpenGL" it does not work.

Any suggestions?